# Can't Query anything in Postgresql 9.4 using pgadmin3

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

So, i have a database that i've already imported to Postgresql in multiple ways, using either the command line or pgadmin3 directly, but all attempts give me the same problem: i can't query anything when using a simple script such as

```
select max(velocity) from taxidatabase
```

because i am greeted with **"relation does not exist"**.

I've already searched high and low and i noticed that error is caused by conflicts in name of databases that use capital letters and such, but you can see i shouldn't have that problem, as i've used nothing than small letters.

So i'm totally lost on what to do. And yes, i'm really still learning the ropes in postgresql so if it is just something really basic like an option i'm missing, pardon me! This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXNE7.png) shows the error i'm getting and some more info you might need.

> I'm using a virtual machine with
>
> - VMware Workstation
> - Ubuntu 15.04
> - Postgresql 9.4
> - pgAdmin3 v1.20

Thanks in advance!

Comment: from your screenshot it looks like taxidatabase is a database and not a table. You run select queries on tables. Expand the tree under the database, you'll see schema, under the schema you should see a tables entry. Expand that, you can see your tables.

Comment: I did it, and i can see the tables, but i still can't query on them.

EDIT: I think it kinda worked. Instead of using "from taxidatabase" i just had to say "from takes" which has all the columns, inside Tables. Dont know if Postgresql is meant to be used like this but as long as it works, i don't mind. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not "Postgres" which is supposed to be used like that. This is how relational databases and SQL work. You query a **table** not a "database"

Comment: You might want to take a step back and read a short DB tutorial. All DBs work like this. A database has tables, tables have data, you run queries on tables.

Comment: I know that, its just that i'm used to other SQL editors where i'm not required to exact the table i'm using, because after all, it has only one table. Thanks for the input!